# C++/CLI: How can I serialize a managed object containing a large unmanaged data structure?

Tags: .net, serialization, deserialization, c++-cli, unmanaged

So, I've been writing a wrapper for some C++ data structures that need to be handled by a C# program, using C++/CLI (on VS2015, if it matters). The data *needs to* be in unmanaged format most of the time, so I'm only converting between types for its most atomic elements, and simply use a (c-style) pointer for data structures.

Here's a generalized example of what I've written:

```cli
// atomic data (unmanaged format)
struct Foo { bool is_bar = false; };

// atomic data (managed format)
public ref struct WrappedFoo
{
  property bool IsBar;
  WrappedFoo(bool isBar) { IsBar = isBar; }
internal:
  WrappedFoo(const Foo& foo) { IsBar = foo.is_bar; }
  void Unwrap(Foo& foo) { foo.is_bar = IsBar; }
};

public ref class WrappedFooVector sealed
{
  // unmanged data structure
  // is expected to be very large, possibly more than 2GB
  // in full code this is actually a pointer to a boost::shared_ptr,
  //   but I don't want to make this example overly complicated.
  std::vector<Foo>* foo_vector_ptr_;

  // called during finalization
  !WrappedFooVector()
  {
    if (foo_vector_ptr_) // equivalent to != NULL
    {
      delete foo_vector_ptr_;
      foo_vector_ptr_ = __nullptr;
    }
  }

  // called during disposal
  ~WrappedFooVector() { this->!WrappedFooVector(); }

  // this function lets me consolidate all the disposal checks in one place
  inline std::vector<Foo>& get_foo_vector()
  {
    if (foo_vector_ptr_) // equivalent to != NULL
    {
      return *foo_vector_ptr_;
    }
    else
    {
      throw gcnew
        System::ObjectDisposedException(WrappedFooVector::typeid->FullName);
    }
  }

internal:
  // access to unmanaged data for use by unmanaged functions
  property std::vector<Foo>& CRef // (C-Reference) - could be named better...
  {
    std::vector<Foo>& get() { return get_foo_vector(); }
  }

public:
  WrappedFooVector() : foo_vector_ptr_(__nullptr) // safety net
  {
    foo_vector_ptr_ = new std::vector<Foo>;
  }

  void PushBack(WrappedFoo^ item)
  {
    if (item == nullptr)
      throw gcnew System::ArgumentNullException();

    std::vector<Foo>& foo_vector = get_foo_vector();
    Foo foo;
    item->Unwrap(foo);
    foo_vector.push_back(foo);
  }

  WrappedFoo^ PopBack()
  {
    std::vector<Foo>& foo_vector = get_foo_vector();
    if (foo_vector.empty)
      throw gcnew System::InvalidOperationException();

    WrappedFoo^ foo = gcnew WrappedFoo(foo_vector.back);
    foo_vector.pop_back();
    return foo;
  }

  property size_t Size
  {
    size_t get() { return get_foo_vector().size(); }
  }

  property WrappedFoo^ default[size_t]
  {
    WrappedFoo^ get(size_t index)
    {
      std::vector<Foo>& foo_vector = get_foo_vector();
      if (index < foo_vector.size())
        return gcnew WrappedFoo(foo_vector[index]);
      else
        throw gcnew System::ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
    void set(size_t index, WrappedFoo^ value)
    {
      if (value == nullptr)
        throw gcnew System::ArgumentNullException();

      std::vector<Foo>& foo_vector = get_foo_vector();
      if (index < foo_vector.size())
        value->Unwrap(foo_vector[index]);
      else
        throw gcnew System::ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
  }
};
```

So far, this has worked well. My wrapped data structures can expose properties and methods that internally access the unmanaged data structure, only converting between data types as necessary. The wrapped structures' finalizers take care of deallocating memory. (I *do* have to worry about stale references, but that's not the issue I need help with right now.)

However, now I need to implement serialization for the wrapped data structure. [Microsoft's documentation for serialization in C++/CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/serialization-cpp-cli?view=vs-2015) is utterly lacking in relevant information. Other resources I could find were interested exclusively in managed contexts (e.g. C#, Visual Basic).

Since the unmanaged object is a data structure, simply serializing using attributes seems to be out of the question. I therefore need to implement custom serialization.

It seems to me that the normal way of doing this is simply implementing the ISerializable interface. However, the SerializationInfo object seems to work exclusively in managed objects; so it seems like I would have to copy all my unmanaged data over to a managed structure of some kind before passing it to SerializationInfo.

Since my dataset is potentially very large, having two copies of it in existence at once is suboptimal. Perhaps there is something I could do with the StreamingContext that would let me avoid this? [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.streamingcontext?view=netframework-4.8) isn't all that helpful.

I'm aware of IXmlSerializable as a potential alternative, however I don't want to be restricted exclusively to xml files (which would be rather bloated).

The last option I know of is so use streams, however there doesn't appear to be a set standard for this, and I'm not familiar enough with the typical use cases of serialization to be confident whatever I wrote would be sufficient.

So, do I just bite the bullet and use a temporary managed object to (de)serialize the data, or is there some way to directly serialize a block of unmanaged of memory that I'm unaware of?